# How can I crop different images using Laravel Varbox?

Tags: laravel, image, media-library

I am using Varbox inside one of my Laravel projects.

I have a custom entity called Post.
Each post can have a main_image and a cover_image.

How can I define different styles for those 2 image types using Varbox Media Library?

I saw there's a `config/varbox/upload.php` for defining styles for images, but I was wondering if it's possible to define individual styles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed there's a config file called `config/varbox/upload.php`, but that acts as a generic configuration for your entire upload functionality.

To achieve what you want, you would have to customize the configuration, specifically for your `Post` model by implementing the `getUploadConfig` method present on the `Varbox\Traits\HasUploads` trait.

Here's the documentation part for reference: https://varbox.io/docs/1.x/file-uploads#specific-model-configurations

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Varbox\Traits\HasUploads;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasUploads;

    /**
     * Get the specific upload config parts for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getUploadConfig()
    {
        return [
            'images' => [
                'styles' => [
                    'main_image' => [
                        'square' => [
                            'width' => '100',
                            'height' => '100',
                            'ratio' => true,
                        ]
                    ],
                    'cover_image' => [
                        'landscape' => [
                            'width' => '800',
                            'height' => '100',
                            'ratio' => true,
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to think about different device resolutions when displaying your images, thus creating multiple styles for both your `main_image` and `cover_image` and display them accordingly.